# SQL Return Monthly instead of Annual Salary & Round to 2 decimal places

Tags: sql-server, decimal

I've been learning SQL in microsoft visual 2015 for the past 4 days and slowly getting used to it, My teacher gave me this homework to solve and im part way threw but now im stuck its a simple Query 
I basically have to bring the Annual salaries up in the table and instead of showing them as annual salaries i need to show them by monthly so (abit of maths to divide them) i also need to round to 2 decimal places.. Here is the question along with my Query

> List the last name of all employees in departments 50 and 90 together with their
>   monthly salaries (rounded to 2 decimal places), sorted in ascending order of last
>   name

```
SELECT Last_Name, Department_No, Annual_Salary AS 'Monthly_Salary'
FROM Employees
WHERE Department_No = 50 or Department_No = 90
ORDER BY Last_Name ASC
```

That works fine I just have to idea how to show the Annual_Salary as a Monthly one nor how to round to 2 decimal places.
Thank you for anyone who can point out the answer and explain a little to me :)
Kind Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ROUND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003(v=sql.120).aspx) function:

```
SELECT Last_Name, Department_No, ROUND(Annual_Salary / 12.0, 2) AS 'Monthly_Salary'
FROM Employees
WHERE Department_No = 50 or Department_No = 90
ORDER BY Last_Name ASC
```

Comment: Thank you it worked is there anyway of removing the decimal places? and  rounding to 2 decimal places.

Comment: @ChrisLad `ROUND(100.11111,2) = 100.11` and `CAST(100.1111 as int) = 100`

Comment: @ChrisLad, if the answer was what you were looking for and helped then please mark it as accepted, in the spirit of SO.